# Python environment different between terminal and VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I am having issues using my conda environment from within VS Code. This is strange because it has usually worked in the past but recently not anymore. I read through some posts to find a solution but was unable to solve it.

I am trying to use a conda environment called `jobapp`.

In terminal:

```
(base)
User in JobApp $ conda activate jobapp

(jobapp) 
User in JobApp $ which python
/Users/User/opt/anaconda3/envs/jobapp/bin/python
```

In VSCode:

```
(base) 
User in jobapp $ conda activate jobapp

(jobapp) 
User in jobapp $ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

So even though the `(jobapp)` indicator is making it look like the environment is active, the python path is still wrong.

How can I make it so it works the same as the terminal?

Comment: If you start an application from the command line, it inherits the environment of your shell. If you start it from a GUI menu, it instead inherits the GUI's environment. On a Mac (which you seem to be on), you want to load a property list with your environment settings when you log in; other desktop GUIs have other mechanisms (on Linux, typically `source` a shell script from your desktop's session startup; on Windows, swear to Beelzebub while you hit the monitor with a dead chicken).

Comment: So you're saying that the issue is that I open a directory in VSCode from terminal using `code .` ?

Comment: That should work as you expect; I would expect trouble when you open it from the Dock (or etc, from the GUI}.

Comment: Interestingly enough, its the other way around. Opening from the dock works fine. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

In VS code, you can change the python interpreter by  press `Ctrl + Shit + P`, then set the path to the chosen python interpreter as `/path_to_your/python`, if you are using jupyter notebook, you should select which kernel your jupyter notebook is using by press `Ctrl + Shit + P` or `F1`, then type and choose `Jupyter: Filter kernels`, you will see a box pops up, only tick the virtual environment python interpreter you want to use and untick other python interpreters.

After this step, press `Ctrl + Shit + P` or `F1`, then type and choose `Developer: Reload Window`, then your choice of the previous step will be loaded, and only one python interpreter (i.e. the one in the virtual environment) will be used.

If this still not works. It may be because the current jupyter extension seems to have problems with the kernel/python interpreter selection. Uninstall the current version and install a previous version, say 6 month ago.

Please keep me updated whether this helps.